# Get child Node of another Parent Node

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have a xml file like below.

```
<Attributes>
<Map>
<entry key="others1" value="display1"/>
<entry key="others2" value="display2"/>
<entry key="Group1">
  <value>
    <List>
      <String>Test11</String>
      <String>Test12</String>
      <String>Test13</String>
    </List>
  </value>
</entry>
<entry key="Group2">
  <value>
    <List>
      <String>Test21</String>
      <String>Test22</String>
      <String>Test23</String>
    </List>
  </value>
</entry>
<entry key="others3" value="display3"/>
  </Map>
</Attributes>
```

I am fetching `<entry>` tag as below -

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource();

DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
inputSource.setCharacterStream(new StringReader("test_file.xml"));
Document document = db.parse(inputSource);
NodeList entryNode = document.getElementsByTagName("entry");

for (int i = 0; i < entryNode.getLength(); i++) { 
   NamedNodeMap attributeMap = entryNode.item(i).getAttributes(); 
   Attr key = (Attr) attributeMap.item(0);
   Attr value = (Attr) attributeMap.item(1);
}
```

I want to get the list of child node values from `entry key="Group2"`.

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please claryfy the exact node(s) you want to get. Right now I don't know if I'm using the correct XPath expression in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help. it worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably best solved by evaluating a XPath expression:

```
XPath path = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

String expression = "//entry[@key=\"Group2\"]/value/List";

Node list = (Node) path.evaluate(expression, document, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Depending on what exactly you want, you need to change the XPath expression and/or the return type.

This returns the `Node` for

```
<List>
  <String>Test11</String>
  <String>Test12</String>
  <String>Test13</String>
</List>
```

#### Explanation of the XPath expression

```
//entry
```

Selects `<entry>` tags anywhere in the document

```
[@key="Group2"]
```

restricts those elements to the elements where the attribute `key` has the value `Group2`

```
/value/List
```

selects the `<List>` elements that are children of `<value>` elements that are children of the elements matched by the preceding XPath part